# Show/ hide element in reactJS does not show

Tags: foreach

I am trying to implement a hide/show element on reactJS and somehow it does not perform as I expected. Here's the code that I have:

```
const editDepartment = (props) => (
  <div id="editDepartment">
    <input type="text" id ='department' placeholder="Enter Department" className="department" value = {ManagerProfile.state.department} onChange={ManagerProfile.updateInputValueDepartment} required />
    <button type="submit" id='departmentButton' onClick={ManagerProfile.sendInfo}>Submit</button>
  </div>
);

class ManagerProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={department: "", student: "", isHidden: true};
  this.sendInfo = this.sendInfo.bind(this);
  this.updateInputValueDepartment = 
  this.updateInputValueDepartment.bind(this);
  this.updateInputValueStudent = 
  this.updateInputValueStudent.bind(this);
  this.editDepartment = this.editDepartment.bind(this);
  }

 updateInputValueDepartment(evt){
  this.setState({department: evt.target.value});
  }

updateInputValueStudent(evt){
 this.setState({student: evt.target.value});
 }

editDepartment(){
 this.setState({isHidden: !this.state.isHidden});
}

render() {
return (
  <div id ='managerprofile'>
    <Menubar />
    <div>
      <label><b>Department</b></label>
      <p> Current department:{this.state.department} </p>
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.editDepartment} >Edit Department</button>
        {!this.state.isHidden && <editDepartment />}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p><i>Enter your students usernames here to add them to your roster. It should be in the format of username@luther.edu</i></p>
      <label><b>Student</b></label>
      <input type="text" id ='student' placeholder="Enter Student Id" className="student" value ={this.state.student} onChange={this.updateInputValueStudent.bind(this)} required />

      <button type="submit" id='studentButton' onClick ={this.sendInfo.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}

sendInfo(){
var config = { headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};
axios.post('/api/managerprofile',{
  student: this.state.student,
  department: this.state.department
}, config)
.then(response => {
  if (response.data == 'error'){
    alert('Invalid student username. Please enter a different username');
  }
  else alert('Your changes have been saved');
  window.location = '/myprofile';
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
}
}
export default ManagerProfile;
```

However, when I run the file and click the button, I see element  shows up and disappears as I click on the button but the tag is empty (I see this in the Inspect element in chrome). So what am I missing that make the  tag empty instead of showing up the  content that it has?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it shows up and disappears because you put it as part of an expression. 
Replace the line:

```
{!this.state.isHidden && <editDepartment />}
```

With

```
{!this.state.isHidden ? <editDepartment /> : '' }
```

## EDIT

Your React JSX component is in lowercase, React interprets it as HTML element. Change it to `EditDepartment`

Comment: I think for reactJS, those two statements are similar. I tried to switch it to what you suggested and it also did not work.

Comment: Oh, yea... Should work but your component is in lower case. React intepretes it like a HTML element. Change the component to `<EditDepartment />`